# Xcode 9 won't allow me to export my ad hoc archive

Tags: xcode, ios11, xcode9

New to Xcode and using Xcode 9 here. I created a new Augmented Reality app project, connected my iPhone 7+ (which is running iOS 11) to my laptop and went to `Product >> Archive`.

It created an archive and I'm looking at this window now:

[image]

The next step is to do an ad hoc distribution/export of the archive to my iPhone, however the **Export** button is disabled. **What gives?**

Comment: Did you added the signing identity properly in xcode .... Because it is same as before only some screens design changes.

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekMishra (+1) - how do I check whether I added the "signing identity" properly?